# Cannot undelete accidentaly deleted files Vista

Tags: windows-vista

I have accidentally deleted some folder (with many files) on my NTFS Windows Vista Home Basic. I tried many undelete tools like "recuva" and many others and non of them helped. I also performed the "deep" undelete with these tools (which took many hours) but it did not find anything.

Is there any other undelete solution? I deleted the files a week ago, and the computer was turned off, so the chance to recover those files should be pretty high ...

I also checked the recycle bin (empty).

The strange thing is, that when I launched the windows search, if finds all the files but I cannot open them (there size is 0 kB) - may be Windows have these files cached from the earlier times?

Thank you for your solution.

K.

Comment: If you have a recovery disk at hand, that'll probably be enough to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance you recover the files using a product called Emergency Undelete.  You can check it out at http://www.diskeeper.com/home-use/emergency-undelete/

To be fully protected I would highly recommend the more robust solution of the full Undelete 2009 product.  Not only can you recover files, but they are protected such that new file writes do not over write the delete files.  http://www.diskeeper.com/home-use/undelete/home-edition/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but the diskeeper is paid, I was looking for some no-money solution :)

Comment: Piriform's Recuva: http://www.piriform.com/recuva  :)

Comment: I have already tried recuva ... it is a nice tool, but it did not solved my situation ...